# Data is passed only once to child VC in container view

Tags: ios, swift, uicontainerview

I am trying to pass data to a container view that will contain any one of several child view controllers depending on the user state. I am successfully passing data the first time the new VC is instantiated, but if I close and reopen that child VC, the data doesn't get passed through again. Here is the action when button is pressed:

```
@IBAction func onMapButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
      let latitude = Double(selectedPlace.latitude!)
      let longitude = Double(selectedPlace.longitude!)
      bringInSubview("mapViewScreen")
      (childViewControllers[0] as! PlaceMapDetailVC).latitude = latitude!
      (childViewControllers[0] as! PlaceMapDetailVC).longitude = longitude!
      (childViewControllers[0] as! PlaceMapDetailVC).placeName = selectedPlace["name"] as! String
   }
```

And the helper methods:

```
func bringInSubview(name:String) {

      newViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(name)
      newViewController!.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
      self.addChildViewController(self.newViewController!)
      self.addSubview(self.newViewController!.view, toView: self.containerView)
      view.bringSubviewToFront(containerView)
      view.bringSubviewToFront(closeSubviewButton)

      UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: {
         self.containerView.alpha = 1
         }, completion: { finished in
            // anything else needed in completion block?
      })
   }

func addSubview(subView:UIView, toView parentView:UIView) {
      parentView.addSubview(subView)
      var viewBindingsDict = [String: AnyObject]()
      viewBindingsDict["subView"] = subView
    parentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[subView]|",
         options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewBindingsDict))
      parentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[subView]|",
         options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewBindingsDict))
   }
```

And finally getting rid of the child VC:

```
@IBAction func onCloseButtonInSubviewPressed(sender: UIButton) {
      UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: {
         self.containerView.alpha = 0
         self.view.sendSubviewToBack(self.closeSubviewButton)
         },
         completion: { finished in
            self.view.sendSubviewToBack(self.containerView)

            // clears out prior view that was there to free up memory
            for view in self.containerView.subviews {
               view.removeFromSuperview()
            }
      })
   }
```

Any insight is greatly appreciated, thank you!!!

Comment: did u check if the data is nil when u open the app again ?

Comment: Can you show the code for  you call add subview after you close?

Comment: The code to add subviews is there. Basically, it passes the latitude, longitude, and placeName properly to the childVC the first time the mapButton is pressed. I can then close it by hitting the close button. However, if I hit the mapButton again to pull it back up, it doesn't pass the data back through. I set breakpoints and the flow is working how it should, only the data is not being passed through the second time. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see problem with your code. In `func onMapButtonPressed(sender: UIButton)` you assume that position is always is 0. It works at the first time because it is there. But after first time you remove it and re-add again in `bringInSubview(name:String)` the position is changed. You should check it.

Hope this help!

Comment: Thanks for your response! It appears that this isn't the issue, I'm calling `view.removeFromSuperview()` when getting rid of the child VC. I ran the app few times through and when I po `containerView.subviews` in the console, there is only one view ever, at index [0]. This is what I expect. It looks like everything is getting called correctly, it's just not passing the data through.

Comment: @can you check it by print `childViewControllers[0] as! PlaceMapDetailVC`

Comment: Ah yes, there are multiple child view controllers on the stack, I'm getting the views back when I po `childViewControllers[1]`. How do I go about solving this? Either removing the child view controllers, or is there another better way? Thanks again!!

Comment: Got it! Instead of `childViewControllers[0]`, I use `childViewControllers.last` and it works! Thanks again.